# More readable/understandable way to define should_receive expectations before the post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec2

I have a way to set should_receive expectations on a mock object, but it strikes me as a bit odd.

```
def mock_fax_event(stubs={})
  @mock_fax_event ||= mock_model(FaxEvent, stubs)
end

it "should notify facility/admin of failed faxes" do
  FaxEvent.should_receive(:find_by_fax_id).with(@fax_event.fax_id).and_return(mock_fax_event(:notify_failure => true))
  mock_fax_event.should_receive(:notify_failure)
  post :create, :TransactionID => @fax_event.fax_id
end
```

To me, I would like to do something like the following, but it doesn't work:

```
it "should notify facility/admin of failed faxes" do
  post :create, :TransactionID => @fax_event.fax_id
  assigns(:fax_event).should_receive(:notify_failure)
end
```

I think I understand why the above doesn't work, but I think the way I'm doing it now is unclear.  I would also like to only test if notify_failure is actually called, not the find_by_fax_id part.

Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Your second example doesn't work because it's a chicken-and-egg kind of problem. You're setting an expectation on an object *after* the `post` call which is what causes that object to become assigned in the first place. And you can't just swap the lines because `assigns` doesn't have anything to return yet.

If you don't care about whether or not find_by_fax_id gets called, the best you can do is call `FaxEvent.stub(:find_by_fax_id).and_return(...)`, but that's not much better.

This is one of the reasons I like using [Mocha](http://mocha.rubyforge.org/). You can do this:

```
FaxEvent.any_instance.expects(:notify_failure)
post :create, :TransactionID => @fax_event.fax_id
```

It lets you skip the annoying "find my mock object instead of what you'd actually find" step.

Also, `:TransactionID` goes against naming conventions, it should be `:transaction_id`.

Comment: Thanks, I will check out Mocha; I am becoming overwhelmed by testing frameworks.  As far as the TransactionID, it's posted into the controller via an external service that I can not control, so not much I can do about it :)  Will wait around to see if anyone else has something to say before awarding the answer, thanks for your comment.